# How to display all values in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using following code but only one result will come.

```
function group($id)
{
    $this->db->select('groupId,groupName');    
    $this->db->from('groups');
    $this->db->where('createdBy',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach($result=$query->row_array() as $row)
    {
        print_r($result);
    }
}
```

How can I display all values from database?.Please help me.

Comment: foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->title;
}

Answer (score 5):

Use  `$query->result()` method `object` returns use `result_array` for returning value in array

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->groupId;//column names
}
```

To use `result_array`

```
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    echo $row['groupId'];//column names
}
```

Comment: :)  happy to help u @A.C.Manikandan

Answer (score 1):

You are printing only one value.

You need to take all values in an array and print it.

Corrected code:

```
<?php
function group($id) {
    $this->db->select('groupId,groupName');
    $this->db->from('groups');
    $this->db->where('createdBy', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($query->row_array() as $row) {
        $arr[] = $row;
    }
    print_r($arr);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[result_array()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)**

> This method returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty
>   array when no result is produced. Typically you’ll use this in a
>   foreach loop, like this:

```
foreach($query->row_array() as $row)
    {
        echo $row['groupId'];
        echo $row['groupName'];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use as below

```
foreach($query->row_array() as $row)
 {
    print_r($row);
 }
```